# Finding the exact selected text index in html document which works on safari and google chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery

how to find index of selected text that is not dependent on window size and resolution?
i have implemented it on IE but that code doesn't work on google chrome and safari as they dont support createrange method of javascript. this the code for IE to find start and end position

```
                range = doc.selection.createRange();
                range.execCommand("BackColor", false, colour);
                var sourceSelEnd = range.boundingLeft;
                var sourceSelStart = parseInt(sourceSelEnd);
                sourceSelStart = sourceSelStart - (range.text.length);
```

Please help in finding start index or position of selected text. 
Position() and Offset() are changing on window resize and resolution change

Comment: A TextRange's `boundingLeft` property is a pixel position and its `text` property is a string, so `sourceSelStart` is a completely meaningless number.

Comment: What kind of index do you want? A character index within the text of the page?

Answer (score 1):

I believe the following should do what you are looking for though it is admittedly contrived to illustrate the functionality:

```
function getRangeAttributes()
{
    var currentRange = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
    return {'startContainer':currentRange.startContainer,'startOffset':currentRange.startOffset,'endContainer':currentRange.endContainer,'endOffset':currentRange.endOffset,'textLength':currentRange.toString().length}
}
```

Please see the following for more information:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/range

Comment: i have tried your example but it is giving 0 as Start and End offset

Comment: See the following: http://jsfiddle.net/VivekVish/yV4ZB/2/ See the following example.  I realize now that if you are looking at textareas this methodology won't work.  If you are looking at regular text from `<p>` elements and other non-input elements, it should work.  For the attached example highlight some text within "Hello?" and hit the spacebar key (or any key for that matter) and you will see the range characteristics in the console.  Please tell me if this works.  Otherwise, I'll work on another solution.